# Understanding Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototypal

```
var Object1 = {};
var Object2 = new Object();
var Object3 = Object.create({});
```

When i check whether the prototype is equal to `Object.prototype`:

The first two return `true` while the third one returns `false`.

Why is this happening?

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object1)===Object.prototype //true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object2)===Object.prototype //true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object3)===Object.prototype //false
```

Comment: Try `Object.create(Object.prototype)`

Comment: But why does this happen ?

Comment: Because `{} !== Object.prototype` (where `{}` is that object you've used as the prototype for `Object3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because if you take a look at the [**Object.create()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) in the documentation, you will that this method:

> creates a new object with the specified prototype object and
>   properties.

And if you call it with :

```
Object.create({})
```

You are not passing a prototype but an empty object with no properties.

So as stated in comments you need to call it like this:

```
Object.create(Object.prototype)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

Behind the scenes it does the following:

```
Object.create = (function() {
  var Temp = function() {};
  return function (prototype) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      throw Error('Second argument not supported');
    }
    if (typeof prototype != 'object') {
      throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
    }
    Temp.prototype = prototype;
    var result = new Temp();
    Temp.prototype = null;
    return result;
  };
})();
```

So the right use would be:

```
var Object3 = Object.create(Object.prototype);
```

Or if you want to make your example work:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object3)) === Object.prototype // true
```

Here the prototype chain comes into play:

```
console.dir(Object3)
 -> __proto__: Object (=== Your Object Literal)
   -> __proto__: Object (=== Object.prototype)
```